# Showing a set is equicontinuous and uniformly bounded

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $C[0,1]=\left\lbrace \text{real-valued, continuous functions on [0,1]} \right\rbrace$, and suppose $F$ is precompact in $C([0,1])$. I need to prove that $F$ is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous.

Here's what I've tried:

To show uniform boundedness, I need to show there exists a constant $M$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for every $x \in [0,1]$ and $f \in F$. So fixing $f \in F$ and $x \in [0,1]$, since $f$ is continuous on a compact space, $f$ obtains a maximum value. So $|f(x)| \leq M$ for each $f \in F$.

For equicontinuous, I need to show that for every $x \in [0,1]$ and every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ so that for all $f \in F$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$ for each $y \in U_x$. So again, fix $\epsilon > 0$ and $f \in F$. Let $U_x = B(x, \frac{\epsilon}{2})$. So $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $y \in U_x$. However, it doesn't seem like I really used the fact that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, so this proof doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To show uniform boundedness, I need to show there exists a constant $M$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for every $x \in [0,1]$ and $f \in F$. So fixing $f \in F$ and $x \in [0,1]$, since $f$ is continuous on a compact space, $f$ obtains a maximum value. So $|f(x)| \leq M$ for each $f \in F$.

No. It doesn't show that $F$ is bounded. You must show that there is an $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\|f\|\le M$ for all $f\in F$. But since $F$ is precompact, it is bounded.

For the equicontinuity, let $\epsilon>0$. We want find $\delta=\delta(\epsilon)>0$ such that for all $f\in F$ if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Now, note that, since $F$ is precompact, then $F\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^nB(f_i,\frac{\epsilon}{3})$ for some $f_1,f_2,...,f_n\in F$, where $B(f_i,\epsilon)=\{g\in C[0,1]:\|g-f_i\|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}\}$.

Now, since $f_i\in C[0,1]$, $f_i$ is uniformly continuous. Thus, for $\epsilon/3>0$, there is a $\delta_i=\delta_i(f_i)>$ such that $|f_i(x)-f_i(y)|<\epsilon/3$ always that $|x-y|<\delta_i$.

Let $\delta=\min\{\delta_i:i\in\{1,...,n\}\}$. Thus, if $|x-y|<\delta\le\delta_i$, we have $|f_i(x)-f_i(y)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ for all $f_i$.

On the other hand, let $f\in F$. By precompacity, there is an $i$ such that $\|f-f_i\|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$. It means that $|f(x)-f_i(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Finally, let $x,y\in [0,1]$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$. Then

$\begin{eqnarray}
|f(x)-f(y)|&=&|f(x)-f_i(x)+f_i(x)+f_i(y)-f(y)-f_i(y)|\\
&\le&|f(x)-f_i(x)|+|f_i(y)-f(y)|+|f_i(x)-f_i(y)|\\
&\le&\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}\\
&=&\epsilon
\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: Hi. Thank you for detailed explanation. I have a couple questions for you: Why is knowing $F$ precompact imply it's bounded? Is it because $F \subset \bar{F}$ which is compact and hence bounded? Also, why do I know that I can cover $F$ by finitely many balls? I know I can cover it by finitely many open sets, but how do I know it's covered by the balls? (Sorry if these questions are simple -- I've always found topology quite difficult lol)

Comment: What is your definition of precompact? I'm guessing you are using other definition

Comment: The definition we have is that $F$ is precompact if $\bar{F}$ is compact.

Comment: Oh, I see. It is not the usual definition. It is definition of relatively compact. A set $A$ is Precompact if for every $\epsilon>0$ there are $x_1,...,x_n\in A$ such that $A\subseteq \cup_{i=1}^nB(x_i,\epsilon)$

Comment: In your case it is a detail: precompact and relatively compact are equivalents in complete metric spaces. Thus, since $C[0,1]$ is complete, proving precompactness, as I did, implies proving relatively compact, like you want.